# Concat string and what a function returns in html/aurelia

Tags: html, aurelia

Is it possible to do a concatenation of a string with the result returned by a method ? Something like this

```
<label for="car + myMethod($index)">
    Car No.
</label>
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="car"
    id="car + myMethod($index)"
    checked.bind="myObject.car" />
```

Assuming, the VM method `myMethod($index)` returns a string like `No2`, can I concatenate it so that the final label's ID will be `carNo2` ? (where the number is dynamically calculated based on the `$index`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal interpolation in template should work:

```
<label for="car${myMethod($index)}">
    Car No.
</label>
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="car"
    id="car${myMethod($index)}"
    checked.bind="myObject.car" />
```